# R Subtracting Vectors Time Series

Tags: r, vector, xts, subtraction

This code works despite the convolutions so I can live with what follows.

It progresses from a CSV file, to a dataframe, to a list back to a dataframe, then to xts/ zoo.

Is there any easier and shorter way for subtracting two vectors?

```
library(xts)
#Step 1  CSV
dat<-read.csv("table(3).csv")
#first row in that file
#         Date  Open  High   Low Close   Volume Adj.Close
#1  2014-04-17 21.85 21.91 21.75 21.86 47892800     21.86
#
class(dat)
#[1] "data.frame"

# Step 2 
h<-subset(dat,select=c(High))
l<-subset(dat,select=c(Low))
d<-subset(dat,select=c(Date))
diff<-h-l

#Step 3
new<-c(d,h,l,diff)
class(new)
#[1] "list"

new2<-as.data.frame(new)
class(new2)
#[1] "data.frame"

#Step 4
new2.xts <- xts(x=new2[,-1],order.by= as.POSIXct(new2$Date))
class(new2.xts)
#[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can interact with the columns directly:

```
dat$diff <- dat$High - dat$Low
```